# how to add a listener for checkboxes in an adapter view, Android, ArrayAdapter, onCheckedChanged, OnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, listener, adapter, android-arrayadapter, oncheckedchanged

[image]

I have a listView that by way of an ArrayAdapter is populated by small xml sub views.  each small view only has two things inside, a checkbox and a string label next to it.

i want to set an onCheckedChanged listener to capture the event of the user checking or unchecking the checkboxes.

for example the listener shown here:

```
 listView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

 Toast.makeText(this, "box has been checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

}

where do I put the listener code? and how do I set it up?

code for the ArrayAdapter:

```
  public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CheckBoxInfo>{
    CheckBoxInfo[] objects;
    Context context;
    int textViewResourceId;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        CheckBoxInfo[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.objects = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row_layout_view = convertView;


            if ((row_layout_view == null)){


                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row_layout_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            }   

          //CheckBoxInfo item = objects.get(position);  // for arrayList
            CheckBoxInfo item = objects[position];

            if(item != null){

            TextView textView = (TextView) row_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row_layout_view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            if(item !=null){
            textView.setText(item.checkBoxName);
            checkBox.setChecked(item.checkBoxState);
               }
            }
            return row_layout_view;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do not use your example `listView.setOnCheckedChangeListener` or `onCheckedChanged` code.

First of all, for `CheckBox`, you should use `setOnClickListener()` instead of `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`. You can get the checked state inside of the `onClick()` function.

Second, place your `setOnClickListener()` inside of the `getView()` function of the list adapter.

**Example**:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
        // Do something here.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this works because of listview recycling views.  As you scroll down and a selected convertView is recycled, the checked row becomes unchecked.  How do you get around this?

Comment: This is correct behavior. When a View gets reused, all of its sub-view children have the characteristics of the meaningless view that got recycled. Therefore, you must update all views and their attributes in `getView()` every time. This includes setting the CheckBox value as well as its `OnClickListener`. In summary, keep the listener and add `checkBox.setChecked()` to set it to expected value in case recycled (or new) view has a different setting.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you David! regarding HukeLau_DABA comment, I solved it by updating the list view object with the CheckBox value inside OnClickListener() . In my case I have a list of places, as can be seen in the next code:

```
holder.placeCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       //please note that objPlace, position and holder must be declared 
       //as final inside the getView() function scope.   
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final boolean isChecked = holder.placeCheckBox.isChecked();
                if (isChecked){
                   objPlace.setItemChecked("yes");
                }else{
                   objPlace.setItemChecked("no");
                }

                placesList.set(position,objPlace); //  updating the list with the updated object

            }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

do not refer to "holder.placeCheckBox" in your onClickListener, you should refer to view which is passed by onClick and cast it to CheckBox so code should look like this:

```
holder.placeCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
            boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox)arg0).isChecked();
            if (isChecked){
               objPlace.setItemChecked("yes");
            }else{
               objPlace.setItemChecked("no");
            }

            placesList.set(position,objPlace); //  updating the list with the updated object

        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
holder.placeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: " + holder.placeCheckBox.getText() + " " + (b ? "selected":"deselected"));
    }
});
```